# Various ways to intuitively draw the graph of $x^2 -y^2 = $constant?

Tags: graphing-functions, intuition

How can I intuitively draw the graph of $x^2 - y^2 = $ constant ? like Intuitively I can draw the graph of $xy =$ constant, like if $x$ increases then $y$ has to decrease so as to be constant and we get a rectangular hyperbola, but how do i think in this case of $x^2 - y^2 = $ constant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions of "intuition" can be fairly subjective, so here is an example of my thought process when I try to visualize $x^2-y^2=\text{constant}$.

First, rewrite it as $y^2=x^2-\text{constant}$. Notice that for any pair of solutions $(x_0, y_0)$, that $(-x_0, y_0)$, $(x_0, -y_0)$, and $(-x_0, -y_0)$ are also solutions. So the graph must be symmetric about the x and y axes.

Also notice that for very large x, we have $y/x \approx \pm 1$. So the further from the origin you get, the more it looks like the lines $y=\pm x$. This can be more formalized with limits if you don't like my hand-wavey explanation.

Finally, look at the solutions when $y=0$ and when $x=0$. If the constant is negative, we have $y=\pm \sqrt{\text{-constant}}$ when $x=0$. Or if the constant is positive, then we have $x=\pm \sqrt{\text{constant}}$ when $y=0$. Assuming the first case without loss of generality, we can see that the graph will never cross one of the axes, because this point corresponds to the minimum/maximum above/below this axis.

Put all of this information together, and you have what amounts to a hyperbola.

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitutions $u=x+y,$ $v=x-y. $ This change of variables has the effect of rotating the coordinate axes by $45^{\circ}$ about the origin, and turns the equation into $uv=\text{const.},$ which you already know how to draw.

Comment: How can the change of variables lead to the rotation of 90 degrees?, I have seen this somewhere but could not recognize? perhaps usage of Jacobian?

Comment: Isn't it $45^\circ$? To visualize the new coordinates $(u,v)$, you could try to mark some points where $u$ and $v$ are both integers on the $(x,y)$ plane.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is 45, I will edit. The best way to see what the transformation does if you've never seen it before is just to look at where it sends the origin and the standard basis vectors, but I'll admit: at this point, I know what it does geometrically just because I've seen it so many times.

Comment: But I know that the graphs of $x^2 -y^2 = $constant and $xy = $cconstant cut each other orthogonally so here you are saying 45 degree?

Comment: @BAYMAX: All I know is that this change of coordinates rotates the axes by 45 degrees (counterclockwise). Essentially, the $u$ and $v$ axes can be drawn on the $xy$-plane as the asymptotes to the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=\text{const.}$

Comment: Sure! just to see that they cut orthogonally we can take dot product of the gradients, that is $\nabla(x^2 -y^2 - c1) = 2x \hat{i} - 2y \hat{j}$ and $\nabla(xy - c2) = y\hat{i} + x\hat{j}$ and $\nabla(x^2 -y^2 - c1).\nabla(xy - c2) = 0$, so they are perpendicular to each other!

Comment: Ah, okay. But you should be aware that you are talking about two different curves: one is $x^{2}-y^{2}=c_{1}$ in the $xy$-plane, and the other is $xy=c_{2}$ in the $xy$-plane. You can draw both of these on the same page and see that they are distinct. I am talking about two different ways of labelling the same curve: $x^{2}-y^{2}=c_{1}$ in the $xy$-plane and $uv=c_{1}$ in the $uv$-plane are exactly the same curve, just viewed through two different lenses. You can draw both on the same page and see that they are the same, because of the definition of $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y.$

Comment: @BAYMAX They intersects in 90 degrees but the rotation is 45 degrees. This is not weird if you can draw like this: https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/zahyou_hyporg-gif.181299/  and compare the axis of symmetries between two sets of hyperbolas.
Maybe I should mention that the change of coordinate involves a magnification, not only rotation, although it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

you have $$(x+y)(x-y)=c$$

So when $(x+y)$ is very large, $(x-y)$ is very small. Therefore $x\simeq y$ for large $x,y$

Therefore the line $y=x$ is an oblique asymptote.

Conversely so is $y=-x$

You also see what happens when either $x$ or $y$ is zero...

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-y^2$ can be factored into $(x-y)(x+y).$ As $y$ goes up in one factor, it will go down in the other factor. As $x$ goes up in one factor, it will also go up in the other factor.

If you want to try thinking of it a different way, try to picture the surface $x^2-y^2=z$. A plane at height $z$ cuts through this, and that's what you are seeing when the constant is $z$. You know what $x^2=z$ looks like, so you can plot this over and over again, adding different values of $-y^2,$ to build up the 3D function.

Here is a picture from Wolfram Alpha: [plot of x^2-y^2=z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IWEc.gif)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want but I'll add a slightly different perspective.  Please ignore if not relevant.

Consider that a circle centre $(0,0) $ with radius $r$ has equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$ in the cartesian coordinate system.  Now imagine the mapping $y \mapsto iy$ the equation of a circle becomes $x^2+(iy)^2=r^2\implies x^2-y^2=r^2$

I like to think of this as a reason why trig and hyperbolic functions are so intertwined.

To answer the question it is a circle under the mapping.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. I'd be happy to change if there is an error.

Comment: Upon reflection I removed the references to Argand diagrams which may have been confusing. If the downvote was for anything else please let me know.  I appreciate the question didn't directly answer the OP but I thought it an  interesting side note and clearly labelled it as such.

Comment: You appear to suggest that the drawing should be one of a circle, rather than a hyperbola. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: OK thanks. Thought it might be.

Comment: Nice thinking, but we have to think of a way of extracting information from this mapping so that we can make the plot(I too didn't downvote).